# Posgresql standard week of year to israel week of year

Tags: postgresql

I have a query to select data and group by date(data year by years), I need to convert select data from standard week(monday to sunday) to israel week(which start from sunday and end on saturday)
my query:

```
select
    data_date, 
    CONCAT(to_char(data_date::date, 'IYYY'), 'W', to_char(data_date::date, 'IW')) as standard_week,
    CONCAT(to_char(data_date::date, 'IYYY'), 'W', floor(EXTRACT(doy FROM data_date::TIMESTAMP)/7 + 1)) as israel_week
from
    data
where
    data_date >= '2022-01-01'
    and data_date <= '2022-01-31'
group by data_date, standard_week, israel_week
order by data_date
```

the result like this: 
[image]

standard week looks ok but israel week was wrong, how can I make it correct?

Comment: Not sure I understood, waht is the meaning of 2021W52

Comment: Also, if you want anybody else than an Israeli (who might know the definition) to answer, you should declare how the Israeli current week is calculated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I explained on top: israel week(which start from sunday and end on saturday) , standard week is from monday to sunday

Comment: @Thescion 2021W52 mean week number 52 of year 2021, it's just the format i need to show on table

Comment: Note that `CONCAT(to_char(data_date::date, 'IYYY'), 'W', to_char(data_date::date, 'IW'))` can be simplified to `to_char(data_date, 'IYYY"W"IW')`

Comment: Ok, starts from Sunday, but that's not sufficient information. What is the first week in a year? What is with weeks that overlap two years?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I will give you an example: today is 2022-09-21
(week data from epochconverter.com)
- Israel week: Week 39 (September 18, 2022 September 24, 2022)
- Standard week: Week 38 (September 19, 2022 September 25, 2022)
.How to know today exactly is week 38 of standard week and week 39 of israel week?

Comment: That's what I am asking you. An example won't help - you need a definition. You didn't address my questions. I'll vote to close for lack of detail.

Comment: In which week is `2023-01-01` in the Isreali calendar?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's Week 1 (from January 1, 2023 to January 7, 2023)

Comment: What is the  first Israel week (start and end dates) for 2022.